# How to change privacy policy link for Admob user messaging platform

Tags: android, admob, user-messaging-platform

I switched from the deprecated GDPR consent library to the new User Messaging Platform, and used the code as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start). The problem is when the user wants to access my app's Privacy Policy link via the popup window included in the library, it goes to an old link that I want to change. I couldn't find any place in `Admob` to change this link. I tried changing it in the Google Play Console, but it is not changing in the app.

[image: popup window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Open your `AdMob` account, then go to **Privacy & Messaging**, then click on **GDPR messages** icon in GDPR section, then click on apps count in the **App** column. A window will appear, you can change the privacy URL in this window.